# How to iterate and filter a list based on some condition in java 8?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a list(list valies are coming from DB and entity class is EmployeeMaster):

```
    employeeList = 
         elementData=
                  [0] = {empId = 1, empName = 'David', empRole = 'Sales'}
                  [1] = {empId = 2, empName = 'Lee', empRole = 'Practice'}
```

want to iterate through and check if the [0]^th contain 'Sales' then put the data into a map else another map

```
   if(employeeList.stream().anyMatch(emp -> emp.getEmpRoles().contentEquals("Sales"))) {
        salesEmployeeDataMap = employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(EmployeeMaster :: getEmpId, EmployeeMaster :: getEmpName));
    } else {
    practiceEmployeeDataMap = employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(EmployeeMaster :: getEmpId, EmployeeMaster :: getEmpName));
   }
```

this code is putting both the [0]th and [1]st values into practiceEmployeeDataMap.
but the desire out put

```
    salesEmployeeDataMap = {1, David}
    practiceEmployeeDataMap = {2, Lee}
```

can someone help me here with java8

here is the same solution with simple loop:

```
   for(EmployeeMaster list : employeeList) {
        if(list.getEmpRoles().equalsIgnoreCase("Sales")) {
            salesEmployeeDataMap.put(list.getEmpId(), list.getEmpName());
        } else {
            practiceEmployeeDataMap.put(list.getEmpId(), list.getEmpName());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if(employeeList.stream().findFirst(emp -> emp.getEmpRoles().contentEquals("Sales"))) {
        salesEmployeeDataMap = employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(EmployeeMaster :: getEmpId, EmployeeMaster :: getEmpName));
    } else {
    practiceEmployeeDataMap = employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(EmployeeMaster :: getEmpId, EmployeeMaster :: getEmpName));
   }

you can use findFirst to find the index "0" th position.
Please share your feedbaack

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge. But if i have more than 2 lements or may be 10 elements. then how can I check in 3rd row onwards

Answer (score 0):

The reason both values go to `practiceEmployeeDataMap` is that the condition `employeeList.stream().anyMatch(emp -> emp.getEmpRoles().contentEquals("Sales"))` uses `anyMatch`.

To put it in simple English, the condition is - is there at least one employee in the list whose role is "Sales"?

Since you do have an employee with a role "Sales", this condition evaluates to true, and **all** the values go to the `practiceEmployeeDataMap`.

Now, as to how to do it in Java 8 - what you call "simple loop" is indeed simple and in my opinion, an elegant solution. Not everything has to be forced into streams, and in this case using streams will simply be less elegant.